# Event close for option in Chosen JS

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

I am working with Chosen JS and I want to get close event to do something in my project. But when I inspect element and write JavaScript code, the system did not return anything. In my opinion, when I click into close button this element was removed before my code run so I can not find class of this element

[image]

[image]

```
$('.search-choice-close').click(function () {
  alert('hiiii');
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

[`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) takes no arguments so you simply simulated a click. You probably wanted to add an onClick handler:

```
$('.search-choice-close').onclick = function () {
    alert('hiiii');
}
```